# How to make realistic old cabin walls?

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to make a really rustic, non-uniform looking wood panel cabin.  The problem is all the textures I'm finding are too perfect.

**Here's a sample render of what I have made so far:**

[image]

**But what I'm really looking for is a way to make this:**

[image]

[image]

Would each panel have to be modeled individually and with a variety of textures?

Thanks

Comment: you could model just 3 different planks, then link-duplicate and rotate them so that you don't create any repetitive pattern

Comment: Yes that worked well thanks.  Also, I found that if I random selected vertices and did random proportional scaling, it made the planks a lot more rough and real looking.

Comment: it really depends on if you need to make close-ups, otherwise you can keep a very low-poly mesh and rather play with bump or normal maps that you create from your texture, it can be very efficient

Comment: I honestly think your problem is more with the lighting than the texturing. I would firstly utilize an HDRI if you aren't already, then increase the intensity of the sun, and given that it's a forest I think a little bit of volumetric fog w/ light shafts will go a long way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this tutorial, hope you have success https://youtu.be/DcfPH4psKX4